# Get data from EXE

Tags: c#, .net

I have requirement, where I need to call application or EXE, whatever output of that application will be, I need to get that data in my application/code.
Just say I have an application or EXE which gets detail of computer like PC name, IP address, MAC address etc etc. My code/application shoud automaticaly trigger this EXE and get all PC data in my applicaion/code.
But above all is it realy possile??

Comment: Why don't you just use .net to get that information, instead of trying to interop with some random exe?

Comment: Is the exe capable of piping this data or dumping it to stdout?

Comment: Because its not just about getting PC name, IP address, MAC addres. But its very much bigger than that like which software installed and so many stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

> But above all is it realy possile??

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can start the process, redirect its output and parse it.

```
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "program.exe",
        Arguments = "command line arguments to your executable",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // parse the line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) and [Process.StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)